# Fails to load Spring application context in tests with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, spring-test

I can't figure out why Spring can't load the application context in a test class defined as follows:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"/springMVC-config/mainController-servlet.xml"})
    public class DiagnosticsControllerTest {

    @Mock
    DiagnosticsService diagnosticsService;

    private DiagnosticsController diagnosticsController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        diagnosticsController = new DiagnosticsController();
        diagnosticsController.setService(diagnosticsService);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(diagnosticsController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRun() {
        assertTrue(1 == 1);
    }
}
```

The file 'mainController-servlet.xml' is in "myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\springMVC-config\mainController-servlet.xml"

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [springMVC-config/mainController-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [springMVC-config/mainController-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I tried to change the locations for the context configuration as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springMVC-config/mainController-servlet.xml")
public class DiagnosticsControllerTest {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from not being able to reference the correct path to your XML configuration file, the truth is:

You are not even using the *Spring TestContext Framework* in the example you provided.

Rather, you are only using Mockito and Spring MVC Test (i.e., `MockMvc`).

Thus, you can simply delete the `@RunWith` and `@ContextConfiguration` declarations completely.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:**/webapp/WEB-INF/springMVC-config/mainController-servlet.xml")
public class DiagnosticsControllerTest {
...
}
```

Comment: Convince someone to move these config files to another location will be difficult : @Mihir Gohel, your solution didn't work. I think the problem comes from the point that I have several XML files (all in WEB-INF sub-folders) ad I have an impression that not all are loaded. After investigating the looooong stack trace, I've discovered other errors regarding load error of some beans: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'XXX_ds' is defined", where 'XXX_ds' is a name of datasource.

Comment: \@Mihir Gohel: When defining `@ContextConfiguration`, at least one error less in IntelliJ: I can declare annotaded autowired controller as follows: `private DiagnosticsController diagnosticsController` with `@Autowired` annotation.

Comment: Nope, there are other beans that Spring can not bind as well as a datasource not found issue. So the initial error saying ApplicationContext not found is still there. really weird :(.

Comment: Can you try with edits i made in code. Not sure but hoping that it will solve the problem. Or you may share github repo link, i will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

`src/main/webapp` is not on the classpath, hence it can't find the file.

See [Spring @ContextConfiguration how to put the right location for the xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377699/spring-contextconfiguration-how-to-put-the-right-location-for-the-xml) for an explanation of why it's bad to put Spring configuration into `webapp`.

The solution would be to move your configuration into `src/main/resources`, and tweak however you're loading the Spring config files to look on the classpath for them. If you're using a `web.xml` file, that should be as simple as prefixing them with `classpath:`.

There are other solutions, but I feel that's the best option in the long-term.

Answer (score 0):

In order for me to get rid of the error "Failed to load applicationContext", I had to upgrade Spring to 4.3.6.RELEASE and JUnit to 4.12. This error happened to me when trying to run a JUnit test with Java 1.8 after I had introduced lambdas, even though the file was located in `src/main/resources`.