# Failed to load ApplicationContext and cant create all beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

I can run my project and run it with no error. But when I run test it can't.
I see the document and step by step.
I don't know where I make mistakes.

config:

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableCaching
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"com.cybertron.*.service.dao",
    "com.cybertron.service.auth.dao","com.cybertron.service.mes.api.dao"})
public class CybertronMpsApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CybertronMpsApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

test file

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class DeliveryOrderControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void generateInvoiceInfo() throws Exception {
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/order/insert/generateInvoiceInfo")
        .param("deliveryOrderId", "2499");
    mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);
  }
}
```

error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'asyncApsTask': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mpsRecordService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'recordService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stockService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mdStockService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mProductService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MProductServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'warehouseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mwarehouseService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageLocationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageLocationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageLocationRecordService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageLocationRecordServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'outInStorageLockService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'outInStorageLockServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'expectOutInventoryEntityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'expectOutInventoryEntityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'relationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DDeliveryOrderAPlanRelationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deliveryOrderlineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryOrderlineServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deliveryOrderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryOrderServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRecordItemService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productRecordItemService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'machineWorkCalendarService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MachineWorkCalendarService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'machineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ResourceMachineService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mProductStatusService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MProductStatusServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'adWfNodeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adWfNodeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'workerCenterCapacityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'workerCenterCapacityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataMissingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataMissingServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'yuseiPurchaseOrderEntityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.cybertron.purchase.service.web.YuseiPurchaseOrderEntityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>       ... 24 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'recordService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stockService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mdStockService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mProductService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MProductServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'warehouseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mwarehouseService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageLocationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageLocationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageLocationRecordService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageLocationRecordServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'outInStorageLockService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'outInStorageLockServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'expectOutInventoryEntityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'expectOutInventoryEntityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'relationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DDeliveryOrderAPlanRelationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deliveryOrderlineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryOrderlineServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deliveryOrderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryOrderServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRecordItemService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productRecordItemService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'machineWorkCalendarService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MachineWorkCalendarService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'machineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ResourceMachineService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mProductStatusService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MProductStatusServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'adWfNodeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adWfNodeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'workerCenterCapacityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'workerCenterCapacityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataMissingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataMissingServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'yuseiPurchaseOrderEntityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.cybertron.purchase.service.web.YuseiPurchaseOrderEntityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>       ... 42 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mdStockService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mProductService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MProductServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'warehouseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mwarehouseService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageLocationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageLocationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageLocationRecordService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageLocationRecordServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'outInStorageLockService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'outInStorageLockServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'expectOutInventoryEntityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'expectOutInventoryEntityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'relationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DDeliveryOrderAPlanRelationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deliveryOrderlineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryOrderlineServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deliveryOrderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryOrderServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRecordItemService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productRecordItemService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'machineWorkCalendarService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MachineWorkCalendarService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'machineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ResourceMachineService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mProductStatusService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MProductStatusServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'adWfNodeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adWfNodeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'workerCenterCapacityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'workerCenterCapacityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataMissingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataMissingServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'yuseiPurchaseOrderEntityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.cybertron.purchase.service.web.YuseiPurchaseOrderEntityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>       ... 55 more

Answer (score 1):

To run your DeliveryOrderControllerTestclass you need to add one more below annotation to DeliveryOrderControllerTest class
**@SpringBootTest(classes=CybertronMpsApplication .class)**

Comment: thank your answer but it doesnt work.it still reminder Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095449/fails-to-load-spring-application-context-in-tests-with-springjunit4classrunner. this link might help.

Comment: i use the application.yml to configurate project and add below annotation .it still doesnt work `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml"})`

Answer (score 1):

I solve it but I dont understand why it can run.
`@SpringBootTest(classes = DeliveryOrderControllerTest.class)`

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(classes = DeliveryOrderControllerTest.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class DeliveryOrderControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void generateInvoiceInfo() throws Exception {
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/order/insert/generateInvoiceInfo")
        .param("deliveryOrderId", "2499");
    mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which starts nothing and tests nothing, hence it appears to work because it doesn't blow up.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Documentation, it worked because

```
 * Annotation that can be specified on a test class that runs Spring Boot based tests.
 * Provides the following features over and above the regular <em>Spring TestContext
 * Framework</em>:
 * <ul>
 * <li>Uses {@link SpringBootContextLoader} as the default {@link ContextLoader} when no
 * specific {@link ContextConfiguration#loader() @ContextConfiguration(loader=...)} is
 * defined.</li>
```

However you should do only the following to write tests for controller

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DeliveryOrderControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private SomeService service;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void before() throws IOException
    {
        controller = new DeliveryOrderController(settingsService);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }


   @Test
   public void generateInvoiceInfo() throws Exception {
      // write test here
   }
}
```

Comment: there have a lot of service in controller and controller have not constructor to assign services.
i have to @Mock all services ?

Comment: Its better to mock services, than to bring up the whole context and load everything.